# Metrics to identify the presence of more than one circle in a set of (x,y) coordinates

Tags: computational-statistics, fitting, computer-vision, geometry

I have a set of $(x,y)$ coordinates that represent any number of circles in a plane. What I am trying to do is determine whether there is 1 or more circles present in the data set. This would normally be pretty easy except that the data that is being generated is coming from a rather imperfect particle detector.

As a result, a circle is on average represented by at most $5$ to $10$ points. The circles can be arranged in any way on the plane from completely overlapping each other to completely separated. An example is shown below of three common arrangements with the ideal image shown followed by what is actually observed in the detector.

Any ideas on clever ways to efficiently distinguish between these scenarios? Emphasis on efficiency because it needs to be done approximately $300,000$ times a second.

## Example 1 - 3 Circles Random Overlap:

[image: Ideal 1]
[image: Observed 1]

## Example 2 - 3 Circles Linear Overlap:

[image: Ideal 2]
[image: Observed 2]

## Example 3  - 2 Circles Almost Complete Overlap

[image: Ideal 3]
[image: Observed 3]

Comment: Oh my. Interesting question. How many data points are there in your dataset? Are the circles perfect up to machine accuracy, or is there some tolerance? Any algorithm will need to provide some lower bound for the number of data points on each circle, because you can put a circle through any three non-collinear points. The brute force approach would be to look at all $n\choose k$ subsets and see whether each one forms a circle up to your desired accuracy. Is something like this feasible (e.g., if you have a very small $n$)?

Comment: @StephanKolassa, the points are far from accurate as they are given by the centers of a hexagonal array of photo multiplier tubes. A point can typically fall anywhere within $\pm 10$ of the actual radius. There is a lower bound of 4 points to form a circle with any sort of reasonable certainty. We have done what you are suggesting as well as improved versions of that algorithm that run in $O(n^2)$ but it's realistically just not fast enough or accurate enough given how noisy the data is.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, I should add that the examples given have more accuracy than the actual data set since these images are generated from idealistic simulations.

Comment: I wonder off-hand if you can estimate a mixture solution for a [non-linear regression fitting a circle to a set of data](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2015/06/08/fit-circle.html).

Comment: @AndyW in reality doing any sort of fitting is going to be too slow. In our best case scenario we have about $5 \mu \text{s}$ to process each of these sets of points. I'm hoping theres some simple metric to determine the points don't look like a single circle that I am just not seeing.

Comment: Are the points usually equi-distributed, as in the examples, or are the points sometimes within a small sub-arc such as a semi-circle or quarter-circle? Is there any temporal information, such as the points p1, p2, p3,... are the locations at times t1, t2, t3,... of a charged particle moving along a circlular arc?